# Problem building project with angular library. ng serve works fine locally Error message is Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have built an angular library. Iam Importing the .tgz It works fine locally but when I try to build to deploy i get this error ' Unexpected value '' imported by the module 'AppModule in'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.'

someone know how to fix this issue?

LIB package.json

```
{
  "name": "sendungs-detail-lib",
  "version": "1.0.19",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

LIB package.lib.prod.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

LIB PublicApi

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of sendungs-detail-lib
 */

export * from './lib/sendungs-detail-lib.service';
export * from './lib/sendungs-detail-lib.component';
export * from './lib/sendungs-detail-lib.module';

export * from './lib/modules/sendungsereignisse/sendungsereignisse.module';
export * from './lib/modules/sendungsereignisse/sendungsereignisse.component';

export * from './lib/modules/dangerous-goods/dangerous-goods.module';
export * from './lib/modules/dangerous-goods/dangerous-goods.component';

export * from './lib/modules/dispo-details/dispo-details.component';
export * from './lib/modules/dispo-details/dispo-details.module';

export * from './lib/modules/colli-events/colli-events.module';
export * from './lib/modules/colli-events/colli-events.component';
export * from './lib/models';

export * from './lib/modules/shipment-info-details/shipment-info-details.module';
export * from './lib/modules/shipment-info-details/shipment-info-details.component';

export * from './lib/modules/sendungskorrektur/sendungskette/sendungskette.module';
export * from './lib/modules/sendungskorrektur/sendungskette/sendungskette.component';
```

APP ->

Imported the Lib as .tgz !

```
"sendungs-detail-lib": "file:libs/sendungs-detail-lib-1.0.19.tgz",
```

```
import {
...
  ColliEventsModule,
  DangerousGoodsModule,
  DispoDetailsModule, SendungsDetailLibModule, SendungsereignisseModule,
  SendungsketteModule,
  ShipmentInfoDetailsModule
} from 'sendungs-detail-lib';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    SendungsketteModule,
    DangerousGoodsModule,
    DispoDetailsModule,
    ColliEventsModule,
    ShipmentInfoDetailsModule,
    SendungsereignisseModule,

  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class ManualDispoModule {
}
```

I tried to build via Jenkins and Ng Build --prod but i am facing the same issue on both sides

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: HOw you are deploying? Do you use a local version of the CLI? or a global version? If it's a global version, both using the same versions?

Comment: @jithil I tried to build via Jenkins and Ng Build --prod but i am facing the same issue on both sides

Comment: @SaghiShiri i tried to reproduce it